# import javascript libraries as variables in template

Tags: django

I have a django page and I add various js dependencies on multiple pages. For example, on page 1 and 2 I have table that I want to sort. So I include following code in both pages.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-sortable.css' %}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-sortable.js' %}"></script>
```

Let's say, on page 3 and 4 I have nvd3 graphs. So I include following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.7.0/nv.d3.js"></script>
<link href="{% static 'js/nvd3-master/build/nv.d3.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-sortable.css' %}">
```

If I need to edit src url of these dependencies, I have to edit all pages containing them separately.
I would like to define variables on js and css static files, so I do not have to edit them multiple times, but just once.
Something like this:

```
bootstrap_sortable_css = """<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap-sortable.css' %}">"""
bootstrap_sortable_js = """<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-sortable.js' %}"></script>"""
```

And then just print it in my template:

```
<html>
<head>
    {{bootstrap_sortable_css}}
</head>
<body>
 content
    {{bootstrap_sortable_js}}
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any standard for this I did miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [block](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance). Block is used for template inheritance. So, you can have 1 root template file, then all your pages just need to inherit the root template.

You can define A css and js block like this.

```
<html>
<head>
    {% block css %}

    {% endblock css %}
</head>
<body>
    content
    {% block js %}

    {% endblock js %}
</body>
</html>
```

Then, you can override the block on your page template based on your page needs.

Comment: I know about block. But I want to use different combinations on different pages. I would need to rewrite js dependencies in it anyway.